# Lass dich nicht vom Bösen besiegen. Is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, infinitive, passive

This is a Bible verse (Romans 12:21).

A) Lass dich nicht vom Bösen besiegen, sondern besiege das Böse durch das Gute.  Römer 12,21

In this sentence, I can't understand why it's `besiegen`. Shouldn't it be

B) Lass dich nicht vom Bösen besiegt, sondern besiege das Böse durch das Gute.  Römer 12,21

I tested on google translater:

1) He lets me come.  --> Er lässt mich kommen.
2) He lets me be punished. --> Er lässt mich bestrafen.
3) He lets me punish her. --> Er lässt mich sie bestrafen.

Is 2) correct? I understand if 2) is correct, that's how lassen is used, and A) should be also correct. In English, we use `be + p.p` after let when the object word of let is the target of the action.  In German, it seems they use just the infinitive form in this case too.  in 2) someone else is who punishes(and he is punished), in 3) He is who punishes, but in both 2) and 3), it is 'bestrafen', no 'bestraft'.
I need a confirmation from a native German.
Thank you!

Comment: For further reading of the bible you might try out e.g. https://www.bibleserver.com/EU.KJV/R%C3%B6mer12 to compare different german or english translations. (the default dropdown is only German translations, on the right top of it there is "alle Übersetzung" to other languages)

Comment: As a very, very side aspect (but I like the finetuning of language) one might say: "Lass dich nicht von Bösem besiegen, (...)" Your given version tends to put the focus on someone who is evil while my alternative goes more impersonal and means rather "unwell/evil circumstances". Your formulated version *might* have a impersonal connotation of the evil as well, but my experience is rather that people use it (especially in religious text) tend to personalize "the evil" into the "evil one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to infinitezero's reply, I think there might be a translation-induced misunderstanding here. First of all, just to make sure we are on the same page, the *lassen* in the examples you bring up is part of AcI (accusativus cum infinitivo) constructions. In general, their structure is `AcI verb + accusative + infinitive`. As you perhaps know, the class of AcI verbs in German is very small (< 10), with *lassen* by far the most commonly used (others are, for instance, *heißen, machen, sehen*). Simply put, in this construction, the `accusative` does the action encoded in the `infinitive` and the (finite) `AcI verb` denotes a relationship between the sentence subject to that action. Eg:

> *Lass ihn gewinnen!*

(= let him win). Here, *ihn* is the actant who wins and the addressee is instructed to allow for this action (ie, *ihn*'s winning) to occur.

**Crucially, however**, your example

> *Lass dich nicht vom Bösen besiegen!*

is not a prototypical example of an AcI. It is a very distinct feature of the AcI verb *lassen*, which, as far as I'm aware, is unparalleled in English (and, in fact, is limited to this one verb in German as well). Unlike in the canonical AcI, the meaning of the infinitive is essentially passive, not active, and the accusative complement is not the subject of the infinitive action but its object. The (non-essential) subject of the infinitive action is added in the form of a prepositional phrase with *von* or *durch*. So, in your example, the addressee is instructed to not allow for the evil to defeat *dich*, ie the addressee. Another example:

> (1) *Anna lässt Bernd [das Auto] reparieren.*
>
> (2) *Anna lässt das Auto [von/durch Bernd] reparieren.*

In both cases, Anna lets something happen, and in both cases, it's essentially the same thing. But in (1), *reparieren* has an active meaning and the subject of the infinitive action is Bernd. She lets Bernd repair. *Das Auto* can be added as an optional accusative complement to denote what is being repaired. In (2), *reparieren* has a passive meaning. Anna lets something happen, namely that the car is repaired. The optional prepositional phrase denotes the person who does the repairing. This analysis points to a slight semantic difference: In (1), the emphasis is on Bernd and the statement consequently has a permission/instruction-like undercurrent, while in (2), the emphasis is on the car getting repaired; there is less semantic value in *lassen* here.

The above-described passive *lassen* construction can be distinguished from an ordinary AcI by looking at the valence of the verb and relating the verb to the actants involved. Usually, there is no ambiguity. For instance, in your example, the prepositional phrase *vom Bösen* would make no sense unless the meaning is passive. Even if we ignore the (non-essential) *von* phrase, the meaning would be unambiguous, among other things because *besiegen* requires an accusative complement, so if you interpret *dich* as a regular AcI accusative (ie as the subject of the infinitive action), we would be missing an accusative complement. Conversely, in *Lass uns ihn besiegen!*, we would be looking at a regular AcI. The *uns* would make no sense in a passive construction because *ihn* would be the object of the infinitive action (the one being defeated) and, as you will recall, the subject would need to be added using a *von/durch* PP, so the *uns* would have no place here. (This paragraph probably sounds more difficult than the analysis is in practice. If you are aware of both AcI types in the case of *lassen*, it's usually intuitively apparent how it should be interpreted. Just think about the situation.)

<sup>Note: Your example (2), *Er lässt mich bestrafen*, is a rather rare case of ambiguity, potentially meaning both "He lets me be punished" and "He lets me punish". It is induced by the fact that *bestrafen* does not require a complement and that a non-essential accusative complement denotes the object of the *bestrafen* action. Within a neutral context, speakers would interpret it as "He lets me be punished", however. *Bestrafen*, as in English, is almost exclusively used with a [in German: an accusative] complement.</sup>

Comment: Isn't `Don't let yourself been defeated by the evil` pretty parallel?

Comment: @userunknown Well, no, the crucial point is the infinitive. In my example (1), you can easily construe a parallel version in English _(Anna lets Bernd **repair** the car)_, but not in (2) _(*Anna lets the car **repair** by Bernd_), etc. Of course you can express the same thing in English, but not - to my knowledge - with an infinitive construction.

Comment: @johnl ok, thanks for the full explanation. to be frank, I saw the usage of 'lassen' in a grammar book 2 days ago(after the post) so I know how it's used. yes, it's different from English. Then,  '1. let me eat' and '2. let me be eaten' are all 'lass mich essen'? (2. is a reduced from of lass mich vom jemand essen).  Of course I guess for the second one, 'lass mich gegessen werden' can be used. Am I correct?

Comment: @ChanKim Yes. For obvious reasons, absent some crazy context no sane person would interpret it as (2), so native speakers would not perceive an ambiguity here. (The correct _von_ phrase would be _von jemandem_, though, not _*vom jemand_.)

Answer (score 1):

Lassen takes the infinitive of the second verb, just as the English "let".

> Let it be
>   Lass es sein

So `lass dich nicht besiegen` is correct and can be translated as `don't let yourself be defeated`.  However B) is decisively wrong.

`Er lässt mich bestrafen` is also correct. The same reasoning as above, the second verb needs to in the infinitive.

Comment: I think, case (2) might even be understood as "er läßt mich bestraft werden" (he allows, that I get punished by some people - he (for instance god) does not help me go out of the jail, for instance). This is only a tiny shift of meaning, just for the enthusiast of language... (but maybe I'm not sure enough in english so I might be wrong at all)

Comment: @infinitezero, so you mean 'let me eat' and 'let me be eaten' are all 'lass mich essen'? as Gottfried Helms said, 'lass mich gegessen werden' sounds more like 'let me be eaten' .

Answer (score 0):

"Besiegen" ist not the noun in this example. The noun is the imperative of "lassen".

> "Lass Dich nicht besiegen" (selbes Beispiel) 
>   "Lass Dir Zeit" 
>   "Lass Dir helfen"

I tried to re-arange the sentence to make "besiegen" to the noun, but I found no solution. If you would change the meaning it could be:

> Er hat sich vom Bösen beiegen lassen. 
>   Das Böse besiegte ihn.

Comment: Hm? _Besiegen_ and _lassen_ are verbs, not nouns ...

Comment: I´m native German and had to use a dict. sorry.